# How can doxygen find related class in the implementation file in C++

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen is a great tool to generate documents. However, one thing I feel uncomfortable is that it cannot generate the relations between classes if they are not explicitly visible in the declaration file. I take the following example to illustrate my point:

```
class Bcd
{

};
class Abc
{
 public:
    Bcd b; 
};
```

In this case doxygen can identify the relation between class `Abc` and class `Bcd`. However, if class `Bcd` is used in the implementation file, then doxygen cannot generate the relation between them:

```
file.h 
class Abc
{
  public:
   void do();
}
file.cpp
void Abc::do()
{
    Bcd obj;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What relationship are you expecting this to generate?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Here, in the second case I want to show that class Abc is using class Bcd.

Comment: I don't think there is a `is using` relationship that exists the way you think it does. Can you point to the doxygen (or any UML) documentation that indicates that this relationship exists?